# Ideas for Building Bridges on topcoder DIV1-1000

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I was practicing for topcoder when I encountered the following problem:

http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13417&rd=16464

I was in div2 where constraints were much easier, so even a brute force checking for each of the possible bridge location worked. But I tried hard to think about the div 1 problem where (n<=200) and brute force never pass. I can't think of any straight forward way I can not apply a DP or greedy or anything I know. I would be really glad if anyone could give some pointers or hints to look into the correct direction for this problem. On all other forums people seem to be going with brute force approach.

Comment: Maybe a greedy algorithm where you keep adding a bridge that minimizes the diameter at each step. You'll still need to optimize the computation of the diameter however, otherwise you'll have an `O(n^5)` solution, which seems like too much.

Comment: I don't think a greedy will give a correct solution. I tried on small example and that doesn't seem to be work.